# Mellin transform yields Bessel function?

Tags: solution-verification, transformation, bessel-functions, integral-transforms, mellin-transform

Consider the Mellin transform on bounded support $(0,1).$ I computed the following:

$$\mathscr M[f;s]=F(s)=\int_0^1 x^{s-1}e^{\frac{1}{\log(x)}}~dx=\frac{2K_1(2\sqrt{s})}{\sqrt{s}} $$

Where $K_1$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind.

> Is that the correct result? I'm not sure I got it completely correct.

> Why does the Mellin transform give an oscillatory function?

> After performing the transform what can I use the result for?

Before posting this question I read about Mellin transforms and how they are used in analytic number theory because of Perron's formula. They can also be used to solve differential equations in some cases.

Comment: Yes, it is [correct](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#E10). And it is [not oscillatory](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.26).

Comment: thank you thank you